# git commit and git ftp push in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: git, bitbucket-pipelines, git-ftp

I want to make a commit in bitbucket pipeline.

My YAML file:

```
image: wagnerstephan/bitbucket-git-ftp:latest

pipelines:
  custom:
    init:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install php7.0 -y
          - php build/build.php
          - git add .
          - git commit -m "Minify"
          - git ftp init -vv --insecure -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" "ftp://$FTP_HOST"
    deploy:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install php7.0 -y
          - php build/build.php
          - git add .
          - git commit -m "Minify"
          - git ftp push -vv --insecure -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" "ftp://$FTP_HOST" --all
  branches:
    master:
    - step:
        name: Deploy production
        deployment: production
        script:
          - apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install php7.0 -y
          - php build/build.php
          - git add .
          - git commit -m "Minify"
          - git ftp push -vv --insecure -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" "ftp://$FTP_HOST"
```

The `build.php` minify all JS and CSS files.

The first step *(git init)* runs without problems, the `.git-ftp.log` file is created.

But next master push runs, *(git ftp push ... command)* it is writes:

```
Thu Mar 19 21:13:00 UTC 2020: Last deployed SHA1 for ftp.[my_ftp].com/ is 23ec1b6f290ff9dd11d5ff700718ed121c54709c.
Thu Mar 19 21:13:00 UTC 2020: Unknown SHA1 object, make sure you are deploying the right branch and it is up-to-date.
Do you want to ignore and upload all files again? [y/N]: Thu Mar 19 21:13:00 UTC 2020: Aborting...
```

It's as if the latest commit ID wasn't good.

Comment: The repository cloned by the pipeline seems to be incomplete. Something like `git clone --depth 1`, that is there're not enough commits in the clone. Try to reconfigure the pipeline to do the initial clone deeper, or deepen the clone yourself.

Comment: how could i git clone in pipeline?